# Find Min Value and value of a corresponding column for that result

Tags: sql, select

I have a table of user data in my SQL Server database and I am attempting to summarize the data. Basically, I need some min, max, and sum values and to group by some columns

Here is a sample table:

```
Member ID | Name  | DateJoined | DateQuit  | PointsEarned | Address
00001     | Leyth | 1/1/2013   | 9/30/2013 | 57           | 123 FirstAddress Way
00002     | James | 2/1/2013   | 7/21/2013 | 34           | 4 street road
00001     | Leyth | 2/1/2013   | 10/15/2013| 32           | 456 LastAddress Way
00003     | Eric  | 2/23/2013  | 4/14/2013 | 15           | 5 street road
```

I'd like the summarized table to show the results like this:

```
Member ID | Name  | DateJoined | DateQuit  | PointsEarned | Address
00001     | Leyth | 1/1/2013   | 10/15/2013 | 89           | 123 FirstAddress Way
00002     | James | 2/1/2013   | 7/21/2013  | 34           | 4 street road
00003     | Eric  | 2/23/2013  | 4/14/2013  | 15           | 5 street road
```

Here is my query so far:

```sql
Select MemberID, Name, Min(DateJoined), Max(DateQuit), SUM(PointsEarned), Min(Address)
From Table
Group By MemberID
```

The `Min(Address)` works this time, it retrieves the address that corresponds to the earliest DateJoined.  However, if we swapped the two addresses in the original table, we would retrieve "123 FirstAddress Way" which would not correspond to the 1/1/2013 date joined.

Comment: Please share the query you have so far.

Comment: For ID = 001, what is your criteria for choosing the "123 FirstAddress Way" addres over the "456 LastAddress Way" address?

Comment: 123 FirstAddress Way corresponds to the earliest Date Joined.

I updated the question with my query.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For almost everything you can use a simple groupby, but as you need "the same address than the row where the minimum datejoined is" is a little bit tricker and you can solve it in several ways, one is a subquery searching the address each time

```
SELECT
   X.*, 
   (select Address 
    from #tmp t2 
    where t2.MemberID = X.memberID and 
    t2.DateJoined = (select MIN(DateJoined) 
                     from #tmp t3 
                     where t3.memberID = X.MemberID)) 
FROM
   (select MemberID, 
           Name,  
           MIN(DateJoined) as DateJoined, 
           MAX(DateQuit) as DateQuit, 
           SUM(PointsEarned) as PointEarned
from #tmp t1
group by MemberID,Name
) AS X
```

`
Or other is a subquery with a Join

```
SELECT
   X.*, 
   J.Address 
FROM
(select 
         MemberID, 
         Name,  
         MIN(DateJoined) as DateJoined, 
         MAX(DateQuit) as DateQuit, 
         SUM(PointsEarned) as PointEarned
from #tmp t1
group by MemberID,Name
) AS X
JOIN #tmp J ON J.MemberID = X.MemberID AND J.DateJoined = X.DateJoined
```

Comment: My sample is much smaller than the application it is representing, thank you though.

Comment: I suppose it is an small example... but why can't you  use group by and agregates?

Comment: Forgive me but I suppose I do not understand your answer completely.  Aren't you inserting each row one by one into a temporary table in a format to group by?  This would be very difficult on a large set of data.

Comment: Oh I missed that somehow.  Yea that is what my query is currently like, I just do not know how to solve the Address issue, I want the Address that is in the same row as the MIN(DateJoined).

Comment: The second method worked for me, but its returning duplicates for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could `rank` your rows according to the date, and select the minimal one:

```
SELECT  t.member_id,
        name,
        date_joined,
        date_quit,
        points_earned
        address AS address
FROM   (SELECT member_id
               name, 
               MIN (date_joined) AS date_joined,
               MAX (date_quit) AS date_quit, 
               SUM (points_earned) AS points_earned,
        FROM   my_table
        GROUP BY member_id, name) t
JOIN   (SELECT member_id, 
               address, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY member_id ORDER BY date_joined) AS rk
        FROM   my_table) addr ON addr.member_id = t.member_id AND rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.memberid, st.name, m1.datejoined, m2.datequit, SUM(st.pointsearned), m1.Address
from SAMPLEtable st
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  memberid
                  , name
                  , MIN(datejoined)
                  , datequit
            FROM    sampletable
          ) m1 ON st.memberid = m1.memberid
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  memberid
                  , name
                  , datejoined
                  , MAX(datequit)
            FROM    sampletable
          ) m2 ON m1.memberid = m2.memberid
```